# Import main entry from secondary entry

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, npm-package

I'm currently migrating a standard Angular library to an nx workspace.

To split the library I'm creating secondary entries. I have:

- `@my-corp/@my-lib`

  - `@my-corp/@my-lib/some-entry`
  - `@my-corp/@my-lib/some-other-entry`

My issue is that some secondary entries have dependencies to the main entry.

`@my-corp/@my-lib/some-other-entry` should be able to import from `@my-corp/@my-lib`.

Currently I'm getting `Cannot find module '@my-corp/@my-lib' or its corresponding type declarations.` when importing it.

In my `tsconfig.base.json` I have my paths set correctly :

```
  "@my-corp/@my-lib": [
    "libs/my-lib/src/public-api.ts"
  ],
  "@my-corp/@my-lib/charts": [
    "libs/my-lib/charts/src/index.ts"
  ],
```

Also import from both (main and secondary) entries work in the workspace demo app.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generator I used the create the secondary-entry didn't do all his job.

I had to change the include in `tsconfig.lib.json` from

`include: ['src/**/*.ts']` to `include: ['**/*.ts]` to include all the file that are in the secondary entries !